# Need help understanding Traefik rate limit 'average' value

Tags: docker, traefik, rate-limiting

I have the following rate limit rules applied to an API service

```
traefik.http.middlewares.my-api-service-ratelimit.ratelimit.average=2
traefik.http.middlewares.my-api-service-ratelimit.ratelimit.burst=100
```

To test it, I ran 15 concurrent requests (using Siege) to the service in question and this was the result:

```
Transactions:                 15 hits
Availability:                 100.00 %
Elapsed time:                 3.65 secs
Data transferred:             0.00 MB
Response time:                2.74 secs
Transaction rate:             4.11 trans/sec
Throughput:                   0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                  11.25
Successful transactions:      15
Failed transactions:          0
Longest transaction:          3.65
Shortest transaction:         1.52
```

I got a request rate of 4.11 req/s even though I have set **average** value as 2. This value further increases along with the number of concurrent requests. According to their docs:

> average is the maximum rate, by default in requests per second, allowed from a given source.

All the requests were from same source (same ip address) but I was still able to cross the max request rate. Shouldn't Traefik cap it to 2 req/s?